# VS Code doesn't hint reacts this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

After the latest update writing React became easier in many places, but very annoying with one.

Upon attempting to write `this.props` inside a React class the editor instead suggests using `this.propTypes` and it becomes the default selection:

[image]

Is there a way to add the hint manually?